# How to get the file path for the yaml file in google cloud build?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm building a docker image of a nodejs server with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

and trying to deploy it to a GKE cluster with this cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/test:${SHORT_SHA}', '.']

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/test:${SHORT_SHA}"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy:stable"
args:
- run
- --filename='/app/kubeconfig.yaml'
- --location='europe-west1-b'
- --cluster='test-kubernetes'
```

The first two steps work perfectly, but for the third it cant find a file I have called kubeconfig.yaml in the root directory of the server, how do I set the file path for the build step to find the file?

If it helps, I'm using this tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-gke

Answer (score 0):

You should change the last six lines to look like this:

```html
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gke-deploy:stable"
  args: ['run', '--filename=kubeconfig.yaml', '--location=europe-west1-b', '--cluster=delete-me-2']
```

It’s more clean and it seems like [this](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration#creating_a_build_config) is the right way to do it.